# extracting specific lines from multiple lists index error

Tags: python

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
import requests 
import re

url = " https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Kansas-City-
1/forecasts/latest"
request = requests.get(url) 
response = request.text 

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml')

for para in soup.find_all('p'):

    a = para.text.split('/n')

    print(a[1])
```

I am trying to print for eg. only the line from the list till 94.5W but its giving me a index out of range error.
This is the output i get if i only do :

```
print(a)
['']
['Kansas City is  232\u2009m  above sea level and located at 39.05° N 94.50° 
W. Kansas City has a population of 475378. Local time in Kansas City is  
CST.']
['Kansas City 1 – 3 Day Weather Forecast Summary: Mostly dry. Freeze-thaw 
conditions (max 10°C on Wed afternoon, min -2°C on Thu night). Wind will be 
generally light.']
[' Local time in Kansas City:  CST']
['View 3 Hour Detailed Kansas City Weather Forecast for Today']
['Kansas City 4 – 7 Day Weather Forecast Summary: Mostly dry. Very mild (max 
12°C on Mon afternoon, min 1°C on Sun night). Winds decreasing (fresh winds 
from the SSW on Sat morning, light winds from the ENE by Sun night).']
['Kansas City 7 – 10 Day Weather Forecast Summary: Light rain (total 2mm), 
mostly falling on Wed morning. Very mild (max 17°C on Wed afternoon, min 7°C 
on Thu night). Wind will be generally light.']
['© 2017 Meteo365.com']
```

But i only want to print a specific line that i want

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the `a` variable inside the loop and printing it, hence the list just has one element and it gets overwritten everytime. Moving the `a` declaration and the `print()` outside the for loop should do the trick

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests 
import re

url = " https://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Kansas-City-1/forecasts/latest"
request = requests.get(url) 
response = request.text 

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml')

a=[]
for para in soup.find_all('p'):

    a.append(para.text.split('/n'))

print(a[1])
```